# Why can't I open an EXE file from a Python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a .py script to an .exe.
I'm using pyinstaller to make it, but I can only open a easy file which contains, for example: print("Hello world"). When I use more lines in the script I can't open it.

I think that the problem is that I'm importing some libraries and I don't know if I have to add them to the .exe when I'm building it.

Here I have the Traceback

```py
File "GraficoTorta.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
  File "d:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "d:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
  File "d:\programs\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.common'
[13372] Failed to execute script GraficoTorta
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'Perl', 'Scala', 'Lisp')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [10,8,6,4,2,1]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Usage')
plt.title('Programming language usage')

plt.show()
```